# Linq to sql Query running very slowly in Asp.net mvc web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

Net MVC Web application in that i have search functionality, the searched result i will filter using states, cities etc. i have done this filtering but my when search for a string it was taking time more than 40 secs even when i use filters also its taking more time. my database tables more than 1.5 millions of records, so what i have to do for fast search result. this is my code

```
IQueryable<ListCompanyViewModel> Companies = (from cindata in _db.MCA_Datas
                             join masdata in _db.CompanyMasterDatas on cindata.CORPORATE_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER equals masdata.CIN_LLPIN_FCRN
                             where cindata.COMPANY_NAME.Contains(searchString)
                             && masdata.Company_LLP_Status == "Active"
                             select new ListCompanyViewModel
                             {
                                 CompanyName = cindata.COMPANY_NAME,
                                 CIN_No = masdata.CIN_LLPIN_FCRN,
                                 Status = masdata.Company_LLP_Status,
                                 IndustryType = cindata.PRINCIPAL_BUSINESS_ACTIVITY_AS_PER_CIN,
                                 Authorised_Capital = masdata.Authorised_Capital,
                                 ROC_Code = masdata.ROC_Code,
                                 Class_of_Company = masdata.Class_of_Company
                             });
```

with this [Reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) i have created my search function. so i have implemented in my application ajax.BeginForm method for search and filtering also. so please help me how could i perform search very fast.

Comment: Please post the two models and your view + ideally the rest of the action that is taking 40 seconds.

Comment: and how fast is the raw sql query?

Comment: @krishKM thanks for reply, i am not used the raw SQL query, but when i run search query in sql server it is also taking same time.

Comment: @Rob thanks for reply, i have written very long coding my action and i have written my view in partialView so where can i post that code its very big

Comment: If you SQL server returns the same performance, it's not LINQ issue. You must optimize your database!

Comment: @krishKM, how can i do it optimize the database

Comment: by adding index and relationships between `MCA_Datas and masdata `. Normalise your table. i.e  could use `Company_LLP_Status ` with a status table. and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185070/discussion-between-amarnath-and-krish-km).

Answer (score 0):

Try making a non-clustered index on cindata.COMPANY_NAME

Comment: thanks for reply, i have implemented non-cluster index on COMPANY_NAME so still its taking time means its taking less time min 20 secs. and changed my linq query to raw sql query.